# Convert text editor to html and then print to pdf

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf-generation

I'm trying to print a pdf from a ZefyrEditor and I know that there is no such feature at the moment. So I read that the only way is to convert Zefyr markdown to HTML and then from HTML to pdf ([see Github issue here](https://github.com/memspace/zefyr/issues/33)), but I can't figure out how.
I have a Json data saved in a document field in Firebase Database (snapsh is my DocumentSnapshot), so if the document exists, I decode the Json and return the NotusDocument and the Delta quill markdowsn to my Editor controller. When I press my button I would like to print my pdf, but obviously it gives me an error.

I tried to use the markdown package, but I can't understand how convert my Json data to correct html data.

```
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:markdown/markdown.dart' as mk; 

 Future<NotusDocument> _loadDocument(snapsh) async {
     testo =mk.markdownToHtml(jsonDecode(await snapsh['referto']));
   
      if(await snapsh.exists) {
        final contents =await snapsh['referto'];

        return NotusDocument.fromJson(jsonDecode(contents));
        
      } 

    final Delta delta = Delta()..insert('ciao\n',{'b':true});
    return NotusDocument.fromDelta(delta);      
  } 

 _loadDocument(value).then((document) {
      setState(() {
        
        _controller = ZefyrController(document);
        testoHtml = mk.markdownToHtml(_controller.toString());

      });
    }

   return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
          title: Text("$dataVis - $nomePaz"),
          actions: <Widget>[

      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.print),
        onPressed: () async {
                      final pdf = pw.Document();
                      Directory appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();



                     pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
                         pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
                         build: (pw.Context context) {
                             return pw.Center(
                                    child: pw.Text("$testo"),
                                   ); // Center
                       })); 

                    final file = File(appDocDirectory.path+'/example.pdf');
                   await file.writeAsBytes(pdf.save());
                  OpenFile.open(file.path);
        },
     ),
```

Comment: Could you add the error you're getting? I am also looking for a solution to this. If you've solved it, please post it here as an answer.

Comment: i have same problem too,any solution?

Answer (score -2):

You can use [flutter_html_to_pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html_to_pdf) plugin to write HTML source to PDF. To do this, you can either use raw HTML source

```dart
var htmlContent =
"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    Hello
  </body>
</html>
""";
var targetPath = "/your/sample/path";
var targetFileName = "example_pdf_file"

var generatedPdfFile = await FlutterHtmlToPdf.convertFromHtmlContent(
    htmlContent, targetPath, targetFileName);
```

...or load the HTML from file.

```dart
var file = File("/sample_path/example.html");
var generatedPdfFile = await FlutterHtmlToPdf.convertFromHtmlFile(
    file, targetPath, targetFileName);
```